# properties of certain semigroup action on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose we have a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $f(x) = x^2 - x$. We are interested in elements  $n \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that after repeated application of f they eventually hit 0. Can we characterize them nicely depending on $p$?

Comment: A cool question! The immediate observations are that: 1) to hit zero you must first hit one (or start from zero). 2) The equation $f(x)=1$ has solutions, iff $p\equiv\pm1\pmod5$, so if that's not the case the answer is $\{0,1\}$. 3) 2 is the other fixed point. 4) Non-trivial cycles appear (of length 4 modulo 23, and of length 3 modulo 29).